Efficient solution of A @ X = B with B a triangular matrix in scipy or numpy
Consider three square matrices A, X, and B that form the linear system:
A @ X = B

to be solved for a particular solution X (which might not be unique).
I know that the matrix B is a triangular matrix. Is there a way to use the fact that B is a triangular matrix to speed up the solution for X?
I am aware that scipy has the function solve_triangular for the case where the matrix A is triangular. But in my case, all I know a priori is that B is triangular.

I'm not sure any optimizations exist for a triangular B matrix. Maybe someone will show otherwise.

Inverse of A is usually found by solving A@X=I.  There isn't a special solver for this case where B is diagonal.

B is the solution matrix. Each column is the results of A@X[,i] Thus the columns of B are not necessarily dependent.  Whatever type of matrix B is, it has no effect on how to compute the matrix X since each column of B will yield a column of X independent of the other columns. ie X[,i] = A^{-1} B[,i]

Solve for X^{-1} using solve_triangular and then re-invert?
